# crontab -> bash script which should start a node script

Tags: node.js, bash, cron

I have following files:

> crontab

```
* * * * * sh /home/georgmoik/check.sh>>check.log
```

> check.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
dt=`date '+%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S'`
if pgrep node > /dev/null
then
    echo "$dt Node.js running"
else
    echo "$dt Node.js starting"
    nohup node /home/georgmoik/index.js &
fi
exit 0
```

When I run the **check.sh** file directly it works as assumed.
The cronjob seems to stop at *...Node.js starting*.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A golden piece of advice: Avoid `cron` (which is inherently broken, all 5+ flavors of it) and use `systemd` `.timer` units instead. They will give you way more timing flexibility with uptime and system (sleep) state awareness, dependency tracking and resolution w.r.t. other system components, proper log storage and management, security hardening and sandboxing and **so** much more on top of that. If your `myunit.timer` fails or hangs, `journalctl -u myunit.service` and `systemctl status myunit.service` will immediately tell you what’s wrong. And your future self will thank you

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: That doesn't look like a `cron` problem at all.  You want to make sure `node` is running.  What it `node` is used for more than just `/home/georgmoik/index.js`?  Write a systemd service that starts, monitors, and if necessary restarts your service.  Cron (and systemd timers) are not involved in that problem.

Comment: Standard cron troubleshooting: first, capture errors from the script by adding something like `2>check.errs` (or `2>&1` to add them to the first log). Second, look for path and environment problems; cron jobs have a very minimal environment (see my answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/784252/crontab-and-binaries-in-usr-local-bin)), including a minimal `PATH`, so it may not be able to find programs, libraries, etc that're normally found via environment vars. Also, the working directory may not be what you expect, so e.g. `>>check.log` may not put that file where you want it.

Comment: it's a `bash` script and you are using `sh` to run it...

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano It is all `sh` syntax, so it should work.

Comment: How do you determine that `node /home/georgmoik/index.js` is not starting? Add an `echo "$dt Node.js started"` behind it. Does the `/home/georgmoik/index.js` depend on being started in a specific path?  Do a `cd /tmp` and start the shell script there. Does it still work?